# Clojure.Spec: error when using spec/cat to specificate maps

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have this spec for a customer (using spec/cat instead of spec/keys for readability reasons):

```
(ns thrift-store.entities.customer
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
            [thrift-store.entities.address :refer :all]))

(s/def ::customer
  (s/cat
   :id uuid?
   :name string?
   :document string?
   :email (s/nilable string?)
   :phone-number (s/nilable string?)
   :address (s/nilable #(s/map-of ::address %))))

(defn generate-test-customer [name document email phone-number address]
  (let [customer {:id (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)
                  :name name
                  :document document
                  :email email
                  :phone-number phone-number
                  :address address}]
     (if (s/valid? ::customer customer)
       customer
       (throw (ex-info "Test customer does not conform to the specification" 
                       {:customer customer} (s/explain ::customer customer))))))

(def test-customer (generate-test-customer "Arcles" "86007877000" nil nil test-address))
```

I get the exception: 'Test customer does not conform to the specification', but isn't the generated customer correct?

Now all the map building functions of my project are no longer working, and are throwing the exceptions, just because I changed spec/keys and countless individual specs to spec/cat and direct specs.

https://github.com/guilhermedjr/thrift-store/commit/a1f625a1aceb2586fdcd3a527cb39089af2bf3ec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into docs to see definition and examples for [`cat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.spec.alpha/cat):

> Takes key+pred pairs, e.g. (s/cat :e even? :o odd?)
>
> Returns a regex op that matches (all) values in sequence, returning a map
> containing the keys of each pred and the corresponding value.

```
(let [spec (s/cat :e even? :o odd?)]
  [(s/conform spec [22 11])
   (s/conform spec [22])
   (s/conform spec [22 11 22])
   (s/conform spec 22)
   (s/conform spec "22")])
;; => [{:e 22, :o 11}
;;     :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid
;;     :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid
;;     :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid
;;     :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid]
```

As you can see, [`cat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.spec.alpha/cat) describes a [sequential](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sequential_q) data structure (vector, list, sequence...), [`keys`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.spec.alpha/keys) describes hash-map- they are entirely different and it has nothing to do with readability. When you use `cat`, the valid customer could look like this:

```
(defn generate-test-customer [name document email phone-number address]
  (let [customer [(UUID/randomUUID)
                  name
                  document
                  email
                  phone-number
                  address]]
    (if (s/valid? ::customer customer)
      customer
      (throw (ex-info "Test customer does not conform to the specification"
                      {:customer customer} (s/explain ::customer customer))))))
```

By the way- since version 1.11, Clojure has [`random-uuid`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/random-uuid).

**EDIT:** Are you sure you want to use `(s/nilable #(s/map-of ::address %))`?

```
(s/valid? (s/nilable #(s/map-of ::address %))
          3)
=> true

(s/valid? (s/nilable #(s/map-of ::address %))
          "test")
=> true
```

Proper use would be something like `(s/nilable (s/map-of keyword? (s/nilable string?)))`... but I think you just want to write `:address (s/nilable ::address)`.

Comment: Thanks! I've been studying a little more and, as my maps are small, it's more 
performative to use array-maps (spec/cat) instead of hash-maps (spec/keys) - in some cases (array-maps have a O(N) complexity while hash-maps have are O(log n)). However, I only made this change to make the code cleaner, without having to create separate specs for each map key. With that, I got a loss, because I can't access the keys of an array-map directly to make an "update" using assoc, for example, unlike a hash-map. ++

Comment: ++ Key ordering is not a necessity, and my maps can undergo changes in their specification. Therefore, looking at all the factors, it seems that it's best to stick with hash-maps. That said, is there a way to specify a map, with spec/keys, using just one spec/def statement, and without having to use namespaced keys (:id instead of :customer/id)?

Comment: @GuilhermeDjrdjrjanSantos I don't know about such a possibility- I would use [metosin/malli](https://github.com/metosin/malli) for that.

Comment: I will take a look! Thanks for the suggestion and availability ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing in `generate-test-customer` is the `spec/conform` result. As @martin-puda points out, the spec requires a vector.
However, you can convert the produced map in your test to a vector conforming to the spec using `spec.unform`, like so:

```
(if (s/valid? ::customer (s/unform ::customer customer))
       customer
       (throw (ex-info "Test customer does not conform to the specification" 
                       {:customer customer}
(s/explain ::customer (s/unform ::customer customer)))))))
```

With that said, I admit that this probably isn't what you're looking for,
but this will provide clarification as to where maps are connected with `spec.cat`.